# Get sharing settings (OWD) options in APEX

Tags: apex, sharing, custom, owd

I develop application, part of which is implementing of OWD settings edition. First phase is to do it as it is on standard Sharing settings setup. As there are multiple options for standard object - is it achievable to get all possible settings for each standard object?